# App working with Reactjs Class but not working with functional react hook approach

Tags: reactjs

The code below works fine with class approach in reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
this.state = {
            message: 'Helloworld',
            messages: [],
        };


        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        this.socket.on('MyMESSAGE', function(data){
            // data goes here
        });



}
```

**Here is my issue:** when I try to re-write the code using functional react hook. it throws error 
**ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable socket**

where do I declare the variable socket.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Helloworld");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

        socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('MYMESSAGE', function(data){
            // data goes here
        });


  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch content axio or ajax
  }, []);




  //return  content goes here



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare your socket variable

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Helloworld");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

        // declare your variable here
        const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('MYMESSAGE', function(data){
            // data goes here
        });


  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch content axio or ajax
  }, []);




  //return  content goes here



}
```